# How to check whether the mouse is moving upwards or downwards using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this solution in another topic. It works correctly when moving your mouse downwards.

However, if you move your mouse upwards with a little curve in it, the console will both log `From Top` and `From Bottom`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mY = 0;
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

      // moving upward
      if (e.pageY < mY) {
          console.log('From Bottom');
           // moving downward
      } else {
          console.log('From Top');
      }

      // set new mY after doing test above
      mY = e.pageY;

  });
});
```

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

So instead of moving <span>straight up</span>, go from the <span>left bottom corner</span> to the <span>right top corner</span> with a small <span>curve</span>. Moving your mouse up or down. It will log both <code>From Top</code> and <code>From Bottom</code>
```

How can I accurately measure if the mouse is moving upwards or downwards?

Comment: Note you will get "From Top" if at any time your y position hasn't changed. ie you might have moved, even just 1 pixel, horizontally without moving vertically.

Comment: The only difference is that you should check `if (e.pageY < mY) { ... } else if (e.pageY > mY) { ... }` instead of just `else`

Comment: Ok I will try. And see what will happen.

Comment: you only get some false positives when `e.pageY == mY` otherwise your code snippet is ok.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I figered out now with the help of you guys. It solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code snippet works fine. Perhaps the only actual thing needed in order to see that you get some false positives when the mouse is moving left-right or the opposite is to make a small addition in your code as seen below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mY = 0;
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

      // moving upward
      if (e.pageY < mY) {
          console.log('Up');
           // moving downward
      } else if (e.pageY > mY) {
          console.log('Down');
          // movement on horizontal axis
      } else {
          console.log('Moving left-right or the opposite');
      }

      // set new mY after doing test above
      mY = e.pageY;

  });
});
```

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

So instead of moving <span>straight up</span>, go from the <span>left bottom corner</span> to the <span>right top corner</span> with a small <span>curve</span>. Moving your mouse up or down. It will log both <code>From Top</code> and <code>From Bottom</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check mouse position 1 second after `mousemove`, And to do this use `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mY = 0;
  
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(mY != e.pageY){// Works only if pageY changes
      if (e.pageY < mY) {
         document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "From Bottom";
      } else {
        document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "From Top";
      } 
      setTimeout(function(){
        mY = e.pageY;
      },500);//500 means 0.5 second, You can change it
    }else{
      document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "Left Right";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

So instead of moving <span>straight up</span>, go from the <span>left bottom corner</span> to the <span>right top corner</span> with a small <span>curve</span>. Moving your mouse up or down. It will log both <code>From Top</code> and <code>From Bottom</code>
<div id="mousemove"></div>
```

500 means 0.5 second, You can change it.

If you little tangle during mouse move it will only check after 1 second, means if you are going upward and between 1 second if you tangled to down by 1-2 px, it will log as upward.

After `0.5` half second it sets position and again check that in which direction you are moving.

**Another way is to check that you moved at least 5 px**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mY = 0;
  
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(mY != e.pageY){// Works only if pageY changes
      //console.log(Math.abs(e.pageY - mY));
      if (Math.abs(e.pageY - mY) > 4 ) {
        if (e.pageY < mY) {
          document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "From Bottom";
        } else {
          document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "From Top";
        }
      }
      mY = e.pageY;
    }else{
      document.querySelector("#mousemove").innerHTML = "Left Right";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

So instead of moving <span>straight up</span>, go from the <span>left bottom corner</span> to the <span>right top corner</span> with a small <span>curve</span>. Moving your mouse up or down. It will log both <code>From Top</code> and <code>From Bottom</code>
<div id="mousemove"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :) :

```
var oldx = 0;
if (e.pageX > oldx) {
    console.log('From Right');
} else(e.pageX < oldx) {
            console.log('From Left');
}
oldx = e.pageX;
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/mBdMvg?editors=1111

Answer (score -1):

```
var mY = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {

    // moving upward
    if (e.pageY < mY) {
        console.log('From Bottom');

    // moving downward
    } else {
        console.log('From Top');
    }

    // set new mY after doing test above
    mY = e.pageY;

});
```

This uses jquery. We select the whole body and add the move mouse function which detects the mouse. The first if statement moves up after comparing the page coordinates and vice versa for else. Then we save the y coordinates into the variable mY

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Fixed it. ok?